# CostMap2D no longer showing unknown space

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d, costmap, ros-hydro, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am running ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have written an application that runs alongside `gmapping_demo.launch` but has its own Costmap2DROS object keeping track of the global costmap. While developing my app, I have been able to use the `getCostmap()` function to get a copy of the character map. Relevant code is shown:

```
costmap_2d::Costmap2D* mymap = globalmap_->getCostmap();
boost::unique_lock< boost::shared_mutex > lock(*(mymap->getLock()));
mymap->saveMap("/tmp/map");
```

I then go through the "mymap" pointer and copy its cost values to a character array.

This used to work perfectly, but today I noticed that the saved map **no longer keeps track of unknown space (cost = 255), instead just saving it as zeros, as though all unknown space was freespace.** To illustrate this, here is the map generated by saveMap():

[image: image description]

I have searched the file, and 255 does not appear anywhere.

I am quite stumped as to why this is happening. The only thing I can think of is that I **allowed Ubuntu to install updates yesterday**, and the navigation packages were included. Has something changed in the way they work? I am wondering if some bug was introduced.

Saving the map via `rosrun map_server map_saver` still runs the way I expect it to.

If there is any more information I can provide, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141051/costmap2d-no-longer-showing-unknown-space/) by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on ROS Answers with karma: 504 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-05-14**:
This is odd. If you run mymap->getCost(0,0) before saveMap what does it return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case anyone has the same problem, I still have no idea what causes this, but I have worked around it by subscribing to the "map" topic, and during callback, copying the OccupancyGrid to a global character array. This includes unknown space, though it doesn't inflate obstacles in the way the Costmap2DROS object would have. I suppose if in the future I needed the inflation, I could use both methods and only copy unknown space in the callback.

---

Originally posted by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) with karma: 504 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0